# Way to detect event on folder

Tags: c#, file-upload, listener, actionlistener

Work on C# .In one of my application I need to upload file  and save to  database.I write a button event

```
private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
}
```

After button click from user  defined folder path I  upload file,than rest of the syntax save in database.I have done above. Now I need to know, if a file save or update or on file if user do any type of action than I need to upload that file automatically.How to automatically active any event ,plz don’t say any type of timer event.As soon as user update file I need to upload it.How can I detect user update file?How can I active event to upload the file?If have any query plz ask.Thanks in advance.Any type of suggestion will be acceptable.

Comment: is this an asp.net application ?

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor the folder using [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the FileSystemWatcher. Create a new instance like that:

```
var fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher(fileToWatch);
fileSystemWatcher.Changed += OnFileChanged;
```

And in following event you can do the upload of the file:

```
private void OnFileChanged(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Upload e.FullPath;
}
```